# How do you go to bed in the day when trying to be a vampire on mincraft pe

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am attempting to role play as a vampire, and I want to go to bed in the morning, rather than at night and sleep through the day. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do this without hacks or editing the game's source code.

If you want to role play as a vampire, make a dark house and stay inside during the day. That is the closest you can get.